# Localization of Password text giving issue

Tags: android, localization

After looking into this issue for almost a day i thought its a better ask on Stack on this issue.There is always a solution doing programmatically which i have found . Like when the lanuguage is English then i set gravity and do it. But this is only giving me this issue with the text as Password.

**Below is the image in Normal Condition**:

[image]

**And this is when i switch back from Arabic back to English** :

[image]

**The xml related to it:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetails"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imvImage"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblTextView"
        android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/textfiled_selected_ipad"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/login_icon"
            android:hint="@string/_tel_no_"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPhoneNo"
            android:background="@drawable/textfiled_selected_ipad"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/password_icon"
            android:hint="@string/_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_click_select"
            android:text="@string/login" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblSignUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/new_user_sign_up" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post relevant layout xml.

Comment: @ssantos: its a simple xml file . if u want i can paste that to .

Comment: Yeah I know, but sometimes it can give more information than a screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it looks to me some kind of bug. My bet is arabic language is messing with your `TextViews` `gravities`. Did you try setting left gravity to `txtPassword`?

```
android:gravity="left"
```